# 2 times XOR cypher encryption on file don't yield the same file

Tags: c++, xor

I tried to encrypt image file with c++ with XOR encryption .
it worked well but when i decrypt it with the same code i can't open the image , i assume they are not the same but in XOR encryption they must be the same

here is the code

```
void xor_encrypt(std::string const& path) {
    char key[65] = "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08";
    std::ifstream input{ path,std::ios::binary };
    std::ofstream output;
    output = std::ofstream{ path + ".hafnium", /*added*/ std::ios::binary };

    char buffer[64];

    while (input.read(buffer, 64)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            buffer[i] ^= key[i];
        }
        output.write(buffer,/*added*/  input.gcount());
    }

    input.close();
    std::remove(path.c_str());
}
```

and here the 3 files : original image , encrypted image and encrypted 2 times image

[1] original image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKHKU.jpg
[2] image encrypted 1 time : https://mega.nz/file/BUMG2I7K#G3PsUeYCwtTCOj2cYSH47t67_WafRZQsRHyIims-EW0
[3] image encrypted 2 times with xor : https://mega.nz/file/FUMywI5I#mvI6Ge2nEw19fDfTEVso7hKMFSggRJcGJ7_g9178LMQ

the only difference between files i see is that they hasn't the same size

why image encrypted 2 times with xor don't yield the same file ?
thanks for answers

EDIT : thanks for answers , it worked well for the image file but when i take other file like a video , it don't work anymore :

original video : https://mega.nz/file/BYU3hQJI#JugOnHZ6_ajnRqHqc18j_j54MqFoIXAUHITSMxbAo48
encrypted video : https://mega.nz/file/JAMFXCRK#DxYqKAvCqda18oC47qOH0Wiec1bmJ7hSlmypczS9LXE
encrypted 2 times video : https://mega.nz/file/VVUT1KiA#f0vf43PkEssAmoHuPIcY722kd1p7nvQheIlIwFkmrzk

Comment: I think you need to read up on stream handling, specifically handling errors in the stream (`eof` error flag).

Answer (score 5):

This is actually some kind of [buffer underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_underrun).

The end of the file is the problem.

You read using `input.read(buffer, 64)` and the last time you execute this, it will likely read less than 64 chars but less.

Then, you still write 64 characters (you just write 64 chars from the array, with the content from before).

Use the following code that writes as much as you read:

```cpp
while (input.read(buffer, 64)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            buffer[i] ^= key[i];
        }
        output.write(buffer, input.gcount());
    }
```

It uses [gcount](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/) in order to count the number of characters read.

I would also recommand you writing binary if you have binary input, too.

```
output = std::ofstream{ path + ".hafnium",std::ios::binary };
```

Comment: Should open the output stream in binary mode too?

Comment: In order to do binary encryption? Sounds reasonable.

Comment: Worth adding it to the answer then? ;)

Comment: I added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked for the image but when i take a video or other file the problem is the same

Answer (score 2):

dan1st already found the issue of not taking into account the actual number of bytes read, and the mention that you need to process both files in binary mode.
It's not a recommendation, if you expect the program to work properly on Windows, you need to do that (you might get away if only handling text, but then an odd file will come and bite you). However, I wanted to note three things.

The first issue I see is that the original file doesn't match. the imgur link doesn't provide the file you used (imgur may have reprocessed it).

Second, the encrypted files are *losing* bytes. The error of not counting the number of bytes read would make some of your files *bigger* (they would be padded to 64 bytes, with some plaintext bytes). I suspect this may have been caused by not using binary mode.

And third, you are using the hexadecimal key of 64 characters is doing what you expected. Your key is formed by the characters '9','f','8','6'... You are only xoring a few bits of the file. What you probably wanted to do is to xor with {0x9f, 0x86, 0xd0, 0x81, 0x88...}, i.e. you should be converting the hexadecimal string into bytes and xoring those. It could still be broken quite easily, but it would be the proper way to use this 256 bit-key.

Comment: sorry , i don't understood the third point , can you clarify please ? thanks !

Comment: The key contains the character representation of hexadezimal numbers. There are lots of characters you don't use what weakens your encryption. It would be better to directly use an array of numbers.